# Bregman divergence and strict convexity

Tags: analysis, convex-analysis, divergence-operator

Let $d_F(x,y)$ be the Bregman divergence of $x$ and $y$. By the definition, Bregman divergence requires strictly convex function $F$. Let $x=[x_1,x_2]^\top$ be a $2$-dimensional vector, I was wondering if $F(x)=\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0} x_1^2+\epsilon x_2^2, \ \epsilon>0$, then, is  $d_F(x,y)$ still a valid Bregman divergence?

In other words, is $F(x)=\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0} x_1^2+\epsilon x_2^2$ is a strictly convex function?

A simpler question is is $f(x)=\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}\epsilon x^2$ a strictly convex function?

Comment: $F(x) = x_1^2$, which is not strictly convex.

Comment: But $\epsilon>0$, does it make $F(x)$ strictly convex?

Comment: There is no $\epsilon$ in $F$. Look: $F(x) = x_1^2$, no $\epsilon$. What this means is that the set of Bregman divergence metrics is not closed.

Comment: I  see... So it is not a valid Bregman divergence, right? Thanks!

Comment: That is right..